# Can't post Form Data for Login - .NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

This is my cshtml file. I think I am doing some mistake here or in the controller but not sure what it is !

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
                {
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div>
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div>
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-default" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                }
```

This is the controller, currently I am just trying to redirect it to another page after receiving the data posted. But it again calls Index() methon after posting/ clicking submit.

```
 public class LandController : Controller
{
    // GET: Land
    private userDBcontext db = new userDBcontext();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(User loginReq)
    {
        return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Users");
    }
}
```

Comment: What type is your model on your razor page?

Comment: its a .cs class

Comment: Obviously, but one of the main reasons why the data won't post is because you have mismatched properties. Luckily someone noticed you missed the HTTP Verb, so that was your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your didn't specify the form action and therefore it's posted to the corresponding page/action by default (e.g. Index). Can you try to replace `Html.BeginForm()` to `Html.BeginForm("Login", "Land")` and give it a try?

More information about the usage can be found at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx).